# Installing clamav?

Tags: permissions, files, clamav

I'm having a problem with ClamAV. First edited the config file, did that then it was "locked by another process". Then run `freshclam` and an error msg:

```
ERROR: Can't create temporary directory /usr/local/share/clamav/tmp.0d41f2a9f7
Hint: The database directory must be writable for UID 121 or GID 129
ERROR: Update failed".
```

Changed the permissions for the directory, still nothing.

Comment: How did you install ClamAV? Why do you have `/usr/local` in the error message?

Comment: sudo apt install clamav, then tried synaptic, then went to clamav and followed the lengthy method. Uninstalled after each attempt. All resulted in this "freshclam" error msg. I'm too unskilled to have done anything with the accessing of any directories, so I don't know why it is trying to create a temp file in /usr/local.

Answer (score 0):

`freshclam` is probably running in *daemon* mode. Check with:

```
pgrep freshclam
```

Also, you can look at the tail of its log file using:

```
tail /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
```

---

Please note that, the normal installation method for *clamav* is:

```
sudo apt install clamav
```

Comment: Yep. Used this method, then tried synaptic, then went to clamav and followed the lengthy method. Uninstalled after each attempt. All resulted in this "freshclam" error msg.